# InterstitialAds are not loading in activity while loading every 90 seconds

Tags: java, android, gadinterstitial

```
private final String TAG = "RedFM_AdsDemoActivity";
    private InterstitialAd interstitialListen;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ads_demo);
    MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.google_ad_app_id));
    // Create the InterstitialAd and set the adUnitId.
    interstitialListen = new InterstitialAd(this);
    // Defined in res/values/strings.xml
    interstitialListen.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_interstitial_id_google));
    interstitialListen.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    interstitialListen.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {              
            loadInterstitial();
        }
    });
    resumeGame(20000);
}

private static final long GAME_LENGTH_MILLISECONDS = 20000;
public CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
public boolean gameIsInProgress;

public void createTimer(final long milliseconds) {
    // Create the game timer, which counts down to the end of the level
    // and shows the "retry" button.
    if (countDownTimer != null) {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
    }
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(milliseconds, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUnitFinished) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            gameIsInProgress = false;
            showInterstitial();
        }
    };
}

public void showInterstitial() {
    // Show the ad if it's ready. Otherwise toast and restart the game.
    if (interstitialListen != null && interstitialListen.isLoaded()) {
        interstitialListen.show();         
    } else {
        loadInterstitial();
    }
}

public void loadInterstitial() {
    // Request a new ad if one isn't already loaded, hide the button, and kick off the timer.
    if (!interstitialListen.isLoading() && !interstitialListen.isLoaded()) {
        System.out.println(TAG + "Listen  ads loaded");
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        interstitialListen.loadAd(adRequest);
    } else
        System.out.println(TAG + "Listen  ads not loaded");
    resumeGame(GAME_LENGTH_MILLISECONDS);
}

public void resumeGame(long milliseconds) {
    // Create a new timer for the correct length and start it.
    System.out.println(TAG + "Listen  resumeGame called ");
    gameIsInProgress = true;
    createTimer(milliseconds);
    countDownTimer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (countDownTimer != null)
        countDownTimer.cancel();
}
```

**1.When I move ListenActivity to MainActivity, at that time ads loading on both activity.

But when I move MainActivity to ListenActivity, at this time ads displaying on MainActivity but ads not loading on ListenActivity.I am getting "ads failed to load : 0 " Please help me to show ads on ListenActivity while coming from MainActivity.**

Answer (score 0):

Use `Test Ad Ids` to show ads in `debug` app. `Ad-mob` new `SDK` don't show `ads` in `debug` mode or make a release `APK` then ads will shown.

Comment: loading ads with  ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712 ( which is provided by google for test ads) , actually its working in main activity, but when ever  i navigate to another activity there its not loading

Comment: Did you try to add listner for call backs. What error code it gives in onFailed() method. And if its "3" then dont worry everything is working fine. Add not loading currently. For other error codes u cans check admob docs.